# How do I flatten a nested For Comprehension that uses I/O?

Tags: scala, for-loop, scala-collections

I am having trouble flattening a nested For Generator into a single For Generator.

I created **MapSerializer** to save and load Maps.

Listing of **MapSerializer.scala**:

```
import java.io.{ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

object MapSerializer {
  def loadMap(in: ObjectInputStream): Map[String, IndexedSeq[Int]] =
    (for (_ <- 1 to in.readInt()) yield {
      val key = in.readUTF()
      for (_ <- 1 to in.readInt()) yield {
        val value = in.readInt()
        (key, value)
      }
    }).flatten.groupBy(_ _1).mapValues(_ map(_ _2))

  def saveMap(out: ObjectOutputStream, map: Map[String, Seq[Int]]) {
    out.writeInt(map size)
    for ((key, values) <- map) {
      out.writeUTF(key)
      out.writeInt(values size)
      values.foreach(out.writeInt(_))
    }
  }
}
```

Modifying **loadMap** to assign **key** within the generator causes it to fail:

```
def loadMap(in: ObjectInputStream): Map[String, IndexedSeq[Int]] =
  (for (_ <- 1 to in.readInt();
        key = in.readUTF()) yield {
    for (_ <- 1 to in.readInt()) yield {
      val value = in.readInt()
      (key, value)
    }
  }).flatten.groupBy(_ _1).mapValues(_ map(_ _2))
```

Here is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readWholeUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readOpUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readWholeUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1050)
    at MapSerializer$$anonfun$loadMap$1.apply(MapSerializer.scala:8)
    at MapSerializer$$anonfun$loadMap$1.apply(MapSerializer.scala:7)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.map(Range.scala:43)
    at MapSerializer$.loadMap(MapSerializer.scala:7)
```

I would like to flatten the loading code to a single For Comprehension, but I get errors that suggest that it is either executing in a different order or repeating steps I am not expecting it to repeat.

Why is it that moving the assignment of **key** into the generator causes it to fail?

Can I flatten this into a single generator?  If so, what would that generator be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for self contained compiling code in your question. I don't think you want to flatten the loops as the structure is not flat. You then need to use `groupBy` to recover the structure. Also if you have "zero -> Seq()" as an element of the map, it would be lost. Using this simple map avoids the `groupBy` and preserves the elements mapped to empty sequences:

```
def loadMap(in: ObjectInputStream): Map[String, IndexedSeq[Int]] = {
  val size = in.readInt
  (1 to size).map{ _ =>
    val key = in.readUTF
    val nval = in.readInt
    key -> (1 to nval).map(_ => in.readInt)
  }(collection.breakOut)
}
```

I use `breakOut` to generate the right type as otherwise I think the compilers complains about generic `Map` and immutable `Map` mismatch. You can also use `Map() ++ (...)`.

Note: I arrived at this solution by being confused by your for loop and starting to rewrite using as flatMap and map:

```
val tuples = (1 to size).flatMap{ _ =>
  val key = in.readUTF
  println("key " + key)
  val nval = in.readInt
  (1 to nval).map(_ => key -> in.readInt)
}
```

I think in the for loop, something happens when you don't use some of the generator. I though this would be equivalent to:

```
val tuples = for {
  _ <- 1 to size
  key = in.readUTF
  nval = in.readInt
  _ <- 1 to nval
  value = in.readInt
} yield { key -> value }
```

But this is not the case, so I think I'm missing something in the translation.

**Edit:** figured out what's wrong with a single for loop. Short story: the translation of definitions within for loops caused the `key = in.readUTF` statement to be called consecutively before the inner loop is executed. To work around this, use `view` and `force`:

```
val tuples = (for {
  _ <- (1 to size).view
  key = in.readUTF
  nval = in.readInt
  _ <- 1 to nval
  value = in.readInt
} yield { key -> value }).force
```

The issue can be demonstrated more clearly with this piece of code:

```
val iter = Iterator.from(1)
val tuple = for {
  _ <- 1 to 3
  outer = iter.next
  _ <- 1 to 3
  inner = iter.next
} yield (outer, inner)
```

It returns `Vector((1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,7), (2,8), (2,9), (3,10), (3,11), (3,12))` which shows that all outer values are evaluated before inner values. This is due to the fact that it is more or less [translated](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html#23.4) to something like:

```
for { 
  (i, outer) <- for (i <- (1 to 3)) yield (i, iter.next)
  _ <- 1 to 3
 inner = iter.next
} yield (outer, inner)
```

This computes all outer `iter.next` first. Going back to the original use case, all `in.readUTF` values would be called consecutively before `in.readInt`.

Comment: +99 for the excellent `breakOut` use-case, and for posting a reply while I was still crafting my own :)

Comment: @Kevin Wright, I wish I've had more time to figure out why the flatMap/map works but the for loop doesn't.

Comment: @huynhjl Awesome.  That worked and is quite elegant.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the compacted version of @huynhjl's answer that I eventually deployed:

```
def loadMap(in: ObjectInputStream): Map[String, IndexedSeq[Int]] =
  ((1 to in.readInt()) map { _ =>
    in.readUTF() -> ((1 to in.readInt()) map { _ => in.readInt()) }
  })(collection.breakOut)
```

The advantage of this version is that there are no direct assignments.

Comment: Minor point on style: rather than `m.map { ... }` it's recommended to use infix notation `m map { ... }`. Here's the [section in the style guide](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/method_invocation/arity1/higher_order_functions.html)